# mongoose eventual consistency when populating virtual fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate, eventual-consistency

I have a schema with a *virtual* reference to a different model:

```
User.virtual('stuffs', {
  ref: 'Stuff',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'owner',
  options: {},
});
```

When a new user registers, I also generate some related *stuff* for it, and I want to return the user-object with the `stuffs` field populated, so I do something like:

```
const user = await (new User(...).save());
const stuff = await (new Stuff({ owner: user._id }).save());
res.json({ user: (await user.populate('stuffs').execPopulate()).toObject({ virtuals: true }) });
```

I assume that the `populate` function operates by querying the *stuff* collection for a document where the owner is `user._id`, just like the one that was saved in the command above.

I've read that Mongodb is only eventually-consistent, does that mean that the query might fail and not find the *stuff* that was just saved? If so, what are the chances? Do I really need to verify that the population succeeded? Should I add a retry-loop with several attempts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be fine, unless you are reading from a secondary-replica. From https://www.mongodb.com/faq#consistency:

> MongoDB is consistent by default: reads and writes are issued to the
>   primary member of a replica set. Applications can optionally read from
>   **secondary replicas, where data is eventually consistent by default**.
>   Reads from secondaries can be useful in scenarios where it is
>   acceptable for data to be slightly out of date, such as some reporting
>   applications. Applications can also read from the closest copy of the
>   data (as measured by ping distance) when latency is more important
>   than consistency.

Therefor, unless you write in one database and read from a replica of it, you should not run into problems populating.